# Is it possible to achieve significant improvement in memory using "The Memory Palace" method?

Tags: memory

I have heard many people talking about the ["The Memory Palace"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_loci) method (*Method of loci*), and how powerful it is.
Is it possible to achieve significant improvement in memory using "The Memory Palace" method, and are there studies that can refute or prove it?

Comment: My understand of how it works, is basically a method of organizing thoughts and memories.  So what you are asking is basically is it easier to find memories that are organized in your brain than ones that are not.  I can say that when I practice it I can retain the memories.  But it is alot more effort to use this method than to just allow my mind to do its own indexing :p

Comment: How do you define "significant?"

Comment: Could you define what you mean with memory? Is it enough to memorize a deck of cards in a five minutes and be able to recite it after a day? Or does the person have to be better at a short term memory task like Dual-n-Back?

Comment: @Christian I mean the later. To be better at a short term memory task. Or even improve the long term memory.

Comment: 'Memory Palace' is a fictional place for fictional people like 'Sherlock Holmes'. Real life people couldn't construct a place like this completely.

However, partial construction is possible as we do by visualizing a location, position items, linking them with previously existent items. Its like magnetic tape, you remember things longer but you need to follow the whole journey.

You can use Peg system (mnemonics, rhyms, analogy) with memory palace for better result.

It works.